# SQL query/procedure to find best match between two tables based on most matched columns

Tags: sql, group-by, rank

I need a SQL query/procedure to find the best matching hosts for a given visitor based on their gender, and the most matching interests and academic field.   I have the following tables:

```
HOSTS: 
HOST_ID  GENDER   INTEREST_ONE_ID       INTEREST_TWO_ID   ACADEMIC_FIELD_ID     NUM_CAN_HOST
   A       M            1                    2                   10                    2
   B       M            5                    4                    3                    1
   C       F            2                    1                    3                    2
   D       F            1                    2                   10                    3 
   E       M            5                    1                    3                    1
   F       M            5                    1                    6                    1

VISTORS:
VISTOR_ID  GENDER INTEREST_ONE_ID       INTEREST_TWO_ID   ACADEMIC_FIELD_ID 
   1         M          2                       1                10
   2         M          5                       4                 3
   3         M          1                       2                 2
   4         F          4                       1                 6
```

Note that all the interest ids are from the same lists and the academic_field_id are as well (but from a different list from the interests naturally).  So I want a query/procedure that returns the top X best host matches for a given visitor based first on gender, than on which hosts match the most interests and academic field.  Where the interests match isn't important (interest_one can match interest_two and vice versa).   So an example output for Vistor 1:

```
BEST_MATCHES (for Vistor 1..only males with most matches) 
VISITOR_ID HOST_ID      INTEREST_ONE_MATCH   INTEREST_TWO_MATCH   Academic_int_MATCH
   1         A               x [one to two]      x [two to one]        x
   1         B                 -                    -                  -     Next best..which is not too good!
```

and vistor 2:

```
BEST_MATCHES 
VISITOR_ID HOST_ID      INTEREST_ONE_MATCH   INTEREST_TWO_MATCH   Academic_int_MATCH
   2         B               x                   x                     x
   2         E               x                   -                     x     
   2         F               x                   -                     -
```

etc.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This is an expensive query, but:

```
select hv.
from (select h.host_id, v.visitor_id,
             (case when h.INTEREST_ONE_ID = v.INTEREST_ONE_ID then 'X' end) as INTEREST_ONE_ID_match,
             (case when h.INTEREST_TWO_ID = v.INTEREST_TWO_ID then 'X' end) as INTEREST_TWO_ID_match,
             . . . ,
             dense_rank() over (partition by h.host_id
                                order by ((case when h.INTEREST_ONE_ID = v.INTEREST_ONE_ID then 1 else 0 end) +
                                          (case when h.INTEREST_TWO_ID = v.INTEREST_TWO_ID then 1 else 0 end) +
                                          . . .
                                         ) desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from hosts h cross join
           visitors v
     ) hv
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply..but um I can't get this to even run (based on my interpretation of the ellipsis and top select values).  I consistently get "Missing keyword"..so clearly I'm not understanding this properly.

Comment: Start with two interests and see if it does what you want.  Then you can add additional columns one at a time.

Comment: Yes been playing with it figured out my problem - twas the missing 'end' in the order by (case ... ) statements.  Thanks.